# Replacing OS X with Ubuntu on an old Mac

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mac, macbook

I have a MacBook 1,1 purchased in 2007, with the following specs:

- MacBook ["Core Duo" 1.83 13"](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook_1.83.html)
- RAM: 512 MB
- Storage: 60 GB HDD
- Model: A1181 (EMC 2092)
- VRAM: 64 MB
- Optical drive: 8X "Combo Drive"
- Processor Speed: 1.83 GHz
- Processor Type: Intel Core Duo (T2400)

The serial number is 4H629HYHU98, can i put Ubuntu on it?

If so how do I install the system?

Booting with *Option* only gives me one drive. I can not mount it to open, as I do not have the options in utilities. All the answers are for more up to date Macs it seems.

I have followed the guide for dual booting, but the options I need are not there.

Comment: Please clarify the exact model number. Also, you said you tried to boot. Where did you get the PPC version of Ubuntu from?

Comment: i  have have edited the question with all the information i can find, i hope it helps you to help me, thank you

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood and thought you were talking about a PPC model. You are using an Intel model (which is easier to deal with BTW). Can you also please tell us what version of OSX you have? Did you upgrade to 10.6.8?

Comment: sorry for the delay it has 10.6.8 on it but nothing seems to work, maybe i need to go back to factory setting and start from there, however it will not let me do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put older versions of Ubuntu on a Macbook 1.1 (although some fiddling is required). Support on old Macbook for recent versions of Ubuntu is limited (which, given that this is not a mainstream application, is understandable). The instructions at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook1-1 should get you going, but be prepared to do some serious DIY-ing.

Comment: thank you, i am new to this and you have given me loads to study.